# How to specify the database path for TypeORM/expo-sqlite?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM for a React Native Expo app, and I want to be able to specify the path to the database (sqlite, through the expo-sqlite driver). I want the user to be able to open a file dialog and choose where they want to place the database the app reads from (e.g. put it in Google Drive so it gets backed up automatically). Is there a way to achieve this with TypeORM or expo-sqlite?

Comment: Any updates here?